# Getting Error in VS Code while running Flask App

Tags: python, flask, visual-studio-code

Trying to run the flask code in Vscode (mac Os x 10.14.15) but getting an error.

First I tried running:
`python3 -m flask run`

But, it showed

> "Could locate a Flask application. You didnt provide Flask_App variable or wsgi.py or app.py was not found in the current directory.

I then ran the following command:
`export Flask_app = app.py`
(though I didnt need to export the variable since my file name is already app.py)

`flask run`

> Could not import 'app'

Please note that I have verified that Flask version 1.0.3 is installed

Here is the code I'm trying to execute:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def home():
    return "Hello, Flask!"
```

Comment: did you install flask globally or in your virtual environment.

Comment: @kellymandem I first created a folder in which I later created a virtual environment and a. py file.

Comment: @kellymandem I picked up Virtual environment from Command Palette, opened integrated terminal (in workspace) and then tried to execute the python3 -m flask run in the terminal. My file name is app.py.

Comment: What file did you save your code to? What's your project/folder layout?

Comment: @BrettCannon I created the .py file outside bin folder of virtual environment. Moving it to the right folder made the program run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python script should have been created in env/bin. Program ran successfully after moving .py file in the bin folder.